# Empty SVG in IE 11 / Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm using this inline SVG on a web page I'm creating:

```html
<svg class="login-icon" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g transform="translate(-519.000000, -574.000000)">
      <g transform="translate(474.000000, 169.000000)">
        <g transform="translate(34.000000, 392.000000)">
          <g transform="translate(11.000000, 13.000000)">
            <path d="M9,3.48 C10.69,3.48 11.83,4.21 12.48,4.82 L15.02,2.34 C13.46,0.89 11.43,0 9,0 C5.48,0 2.44,2.02 0.96,4.96 L3.87,7.22 C4.6,5.05 6.62,3.48 9,3.48 L9,3.48 Z" fill="#EA4335"></path>
            <path d="M17.64,9.2 C17.64,8.46 17.58,7.92 17.45,7.36 L9,7.36 L9,10.7 L13.96,10.7 C13.86,11.53 13.32,12.78 12.12,13.62 L14.96,15.82 C16.66,14.25 17.64,11.94 17.64,9.2 L17.64,9.2 Z" fill="#4285F4"></path>
            <path d="M3.88,10.78 C3.69,10.22 3.58,9.62 3.58,9 C3.58,8.38 3.69,7.78 3.87,7.22 L0.96,4.96 C0.35,6.18 0,7.55 0,9 C0,10.45 0.35,11.82 0.96,13.04 L3.88,10.78 L3.88,10.78 Z" fill="#FBBC05"></path>
            <path d="M9,18 C11.43,18 13.47,17.2 14.96,15.82 L12.12,13.62 C11.36,14.15 10.34,14.52 9,14.52 C6.62,14.52 4.6,12.95 3.88,10.78 L0.97,13.04 C2.45,15.98 5.48,18 9,18 L9,18 Z" fill="#34A853"></path>
            <polygon points="0 0 18 0 18 18 0 18"></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It renders correctly in all browsers on my Mac (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), iPad (Chrome, Safari), and Android phone (Chrome, Internet). Windows 10 is a different story, however. It renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but not at all in IE 11 and Edge. In those two browsers, the contents of the SVG element are gone for some reason. They literally render this:

```
<svg class="login-icon" viewBox="0 0 18 18"></svg>
```

The page begins with an HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I've got this in the head element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

And the `login-icon` class defines width and height properties (18px each).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which versions were you testing? I'm testing in Edge 38, and the SVG renders for me. I also see the SVG in IE 11.0.14x as well. Can you link to a resource where this element *is not* rendering as expected?

Comment: I've got Edge 25 and IE 11.212. Here's what _really_ weird: If I inspect the page in Chrome and copy the contents of the SVG, then inspect the page in Edge/IE and paste, the SVG renders as expected in Edge/IE. I am using React, which means the SVG is being written to the DOM at runtime, so maybe it has something to do with the interaction between React and Edge/IE.

Comment: Can you setup a small page (at little code as possible) that reproduces the issue? I am an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and would like to know if this issue has been resolved in recent builds or not 

Comment: I've set it up here, and it reproduces the issue for me: http://www.robjohansen.com/

Comment: I see the issue on that domain; thank you. I'll investigate, and file a ticket. Would it be possible to get a non-minified copy of your JavaScript?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.robjohansen.com/wfw.bundle.min.js

Comment: In case it helps, I also used the exact same SVG on this page—but it renders just fine in IE and Edge. I'm racking my brain to figure out what the difference is: https://rob.socrative.com/login/teacher/

Comment: I believe React is a relevant component here. I'm currently exploring that thread.